# How can I transform top level dependencies from mvn dependency:tree into a list of Maven coordinates using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, maven, grep, spark-submit

To enable creating a spark submit command for my applications without creating uber-jars, I want to create a comma separated list of maven coordinates of the applications top level dependencies during my build process, which I can then use in `spark-submit` with `--packages=` (or `spark.jars.packages=`).

This list can be retrieved using `mvn dependency:tree' which outputs a list with this format:

```
[INFO] com.myorg:my-project:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:jar:2.11.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] +- io.circe:circe-config_2.11:jar:0.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.circe:circe-core_2.11:jar:0.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.circe:circe-numbers_2.11:jar:0.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.typelevel:cats-core_2.11:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.typelevel:cats-kernel_2.11:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.typelevel:machinist_2.11:jar:0.6.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11:jar:3.0.8:test
[INFO] |  \- org.scalactic:scalactic_2.11:jar:3.0.8:test
[INFO] \- org.mock-server:mockserver-netty:jar:5.6.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.mock-server:mockserver-client-java:jar:5.6.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.mock-server:mockserver-core:jar:5.6.1:test
[INFO]    |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.35.Final:test
[INFO]    |  +- com.github.java-json-tools:json-schema-validator:jar:2.2.10:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- javax.mail:mailapi:jar:1.4.3:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:jar:8.0.0:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO]    |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO]    |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO]    |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.2:test
[INFO]    +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.35.Final:test
[INFO]    +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.35.Final:test
[INFO]    \- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.35.Final:test
[INFO]       \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.35.Final:test
```

Note that the top level dependencies are preceded by `"[INFO] +- "` (with a single space after the `'-'`).

Only the `":jar:"` dependencies are relevant and out of those only the `":compile"` dependencies.

I want to only output the lines that meet all the following coniditions:

- starting with `"[INFO] +- "`
- containing `":jar:"`
- containing `":compile"`

and from these extract the `orginization:package:version` like so:
`org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.12:compile` ==> `org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.12`

then concatenate these outputs delimited by commas (`,`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution worked for me:

`mvn dependency:tree | grep -e '^\[.*\I\N\F\O.*\][[:space:]]+-[[:space:]]' | grep -e ':\j\a\r:' | grep -e ':\c\o\m\p\i\l\e$' | cut -d ' ' -f3 | sed 's/:jar:/:/g' | sed 's/:compile//g' | paste -sd ','`

This takes into account escaping special characters like spaces and brackets that normally interfere with `grep`.

The `grep` commands do the string filtering, the `cut` command tokenizing and selecting column, the `sed` commands replacing strings and the `paste` command for concatenation.